# Pre-Installed Apps Not Working - Firejail Error

Tags: command-line, firejail

I'm new to linux.

Out of curiosity, I run some commands as sudo to mess up with permissions. When I restarted my system, most of the apps give firejail error.

For Example If I run firefox then it says:

`Error: cannot create /run/firejail/profile/3535`

This same error appears in most of the apps like rhythombox, vlc, dolphin when i launch them in terminal by just typing their name. When I launch them directly, nothing happens after some loading. I hope I'm not the first one to get this error because of my stupidity. Please Help.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, what firefox you have installed (deb installed, snap installed etc), and if run from terminal the command used.

Answer (score 0):

This Is Happening due to problem in config files in firejail.

Just reinstall it with:

`sudo apt reinstall firejail`

It worked for me.